# How to configure SSL for CouchDB

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-12.04, couchdb

How do I configure Couchdb to use ssl, I've followed the instructions [here](https://couchdb-13.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuring/#configuring-ssl-network-sockets) with no success.

I generate my own self-signed certificate:

```
mkdir cert && cd cert
openssl genrsa > privkey.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out mycert.pem -days 1095
```

I uncomment the relevent lines in */usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini*

```
httpsd = {couch_httpd, start_link, [https]}
```

and point to my certificates

```
cert_file = /usr/local/etc/couchdb/certs/mycert.pem
key_file = /usr/local/etc/couchdb/certs/privkey.pem
```

But when I try test it

```
curl -k -v https://127.0.0.1:6984
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 6984 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 127.0.0.1:6984 
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 127.0.0.1:6984
```

I'm really not sure what is wrong.

**Notes**

I've installed couchdb 1.2 from source as per the instructions [here](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/source.html).

Comment: probably a typo, but you typed `mkdir cert && cd cert` and then you have `/usr/local/etc/couchdb/cert__s__` in your `local.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

So I executed the following commands:

```
# openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048

# openssl req -new -x509 -key localhost.key -out localhost.crt -days 3650 -subj /CN=localhost
```

After that, I configure the the local.ini as follow: (making sure that those certificate files are acessible from couchdb user):

```
[daemons]
httpsd = {couch_httpd, start_link, [https]}

[ssl]
cert_file = /opt/couchdb/etc/cert/localhost.crt
key_file = /opt/couchdb/etc/cert/localhost.key
```

When I run this command at my pc, this works fine:

```
curl -v -k https://localhost:6984/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going crazy with basically the same issue, but on RHEL6 with CouchDB 1.6.1.

Browsing through endless mailing lists, realization dawned on me that it was likely an "unidentified" problem with the erlang SSL libraries causing this silent fail.

My workaround (which does work for me) was to use [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html).

- Download/install
- Create your certs as before

Here's a draft setup for stunnel assuming you have a key/crt pair self-signed with open SSL:

```
fips = no

[couchdb]
accept = 6984
key = [path to your key file]
cert = [path to your cert file]
connect = 127.0.0.1:5984
```

Note that stunnel was whining about something related to FIPS on my local, so I ended up disabling it for quick gratification, hence the `fips = no` line.